# Change the Label of a Radio button on selecting the Radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I want to change the radio Button text after selecting that Radio button like,
If the first radio button is selected, the text should change from `Checkout as a guest` to `Checkout as a guest --> Please Press continue`.

If they select the second radio button the text should change from `Register an account` to `Register an account --> Please Press Continue`

```
<div class="PL40" style="line-height: 2;">
    <dl>
        <dd>
            <label>
                <div class="radio" id="uniform-checkout_type_guest">
                    <span class="">
                        <input name="checkout_type" id="checkout_type_guest" value="guest" type="radio" onclick="$('#BillingDetailsLabel').html('Billing Details');">
                    </span>
                </div>
                Checkout as a guest
            </label>
        </dd>
        <dd>
            <label>
                <div class="radio" id="uniform-checkout_type_register">
                    <span class="checked">
                        <input name="checkout_type" id="checkout_type_register" value="register" checked="checked" type="radio" onclick="$('#BillingDetailsLabel').html('Billing &amp; Account Details');">
                    </span>
                </div>
                Register an account
            </label>
        </dd>
        <dd class="Submit mt10 mb10">
            <input type="submit" id="CreateAccountButton" value="Continue" class="btn"> 
            <span class="LoadingIndicator" style="display: none">
                <img src="https://cdn6.bigcommerce.com/r-b99d97b0aae9cde0306565d8de6f047a25afdd8a/themes/Artify/images/Loading.gif" alt="">
            </span>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("input[name='checkout_type']").click(function() {
    $('#uniform-checkout_type_guest').text('Checkout as Guest');
    $( "#uniform-checkout_type_guest" ).append( "<strong>---Hello</strong>" )
});
```

Comment: Waiting for you to post the JavaScript code you've tried so far.

Comment: $("input[name='checkout_type']").click(function() {
      $('#uniform-checkout_type_guest').text('Checkout as Guest');
    $( "#uniform-checkout_type_guest" ).append( "<strong>---Hello</strong>" )
     
 });

Comment: Hi i have put Code What i have used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are three changes you can make so your jQuery is more consise:

1. Put label text in a `span`element
2. Give the `span` elements a common class - `radio-label`
3. Add a `data` attribute to your radio buttons - `data-default-text`

```js
//wait for DOM ready event
$(function() {
  
    //attach a change event listener to the radio buttons -- could give them a common class
    $(':radio[name=checkout_type]').on('change', function() {
        //reset labels
        $('.radio-label').text( function() { 
            return $(this).closest('label').find(':radio').data('default-text'); 
        });
        
        //set new label per checked radio
        $(this).closest('label').children('.radio-label')
        .text( $(this).data('default-text') + ' -->  Please Press Continue' );
    })
    
    //trigger change in case a radio is selected when page loads
    .change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="PL40" style="line-height: 2;">
    <dl>
        <dd>
            <label>
                <div class="radio" id="uniform-checkout_type_guest">
                    <span class="">
                        <input name="checkout_type" id="checkout_type_guest" value="guest" type="radio" onclick="$('#BillingDetailsLabel').html('Billing Details');" data-default-text="Checkout as a guest">
                    </span>
                </div>
                <span class="radio-label">Checkout as a guest</span>
            </label>
        </dd>
        <dd>
            <label>
                <div class="radio" id="uniform-checkout_type_register">
                    <span class="checked">
                        <input name="checkout_type" id="checkout_type_register" value="register" checked="checked" type="radio" onclick="$('#BillingDetailsLabel').html('Billing &amp; Account Details');" data-default-text="Register an account">
                    </span>
                </div>
                <span class="radio-label">Register an account</span>
            </label>
        </dd>
        <dd class="Submit mt10 mb10">
            <input type="submit" id="CreateAccountButton" value="Continue" class="btn"> 
            <span class="LoadingIndicator" style="display: none">
                <img src="https://cdn6.bigcommerce.com/r-b99d97b0aae9cde0306565d8de6f047a25afdd8a/themes/Artify/images/Loading.gif" alt="">
            </span>
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE:** This answer assumes you are using jQuery Mobile as you have that tag on your question.

Set up plain radio buttons and let jQM enhance them:

```
<dd>
    <label>
        <input name="checkout_type" id="checkout_type_guest" value="guest" type="radio" />
        Checkout as a guest
    </label>
</dd>
<dd>
    <label>
        <input name="checkout_type" id="checkout_type_register" value="register" checked="checked" type="radio" />
        Register an account
    </label>
</dd>
```

Then listen for the change event:

```
$("input[name='checkout_type']").on("change", function() {       
    $("input[name='checkout_type']").each(function(){
        var text = '';
        if ($(this).val() == "guest"){
            text = "Checkout as a guest";
        } else {
            text = "Register an account";
        }
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            text += " --> Please Press continue";   
        }
        $(this).closest(".ui-radio").find("label.ui-btn").text(text);
    });
});
```

Loop through each radio button, see if it is checked and then set the text accordingly.

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/ye727qps/)**

### UPDATE:

Using PeterKA's data attribute for the default text makes the code even nicer:

```
$("input[name='checkout_type']").on("change", function() {       
    $("input[name='checkout_type']").each(function(){
        var text = $(this).data('default-text');
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            text += " --> Please Press continue";   
        }
        $(this).closest(".ui-radio").find("label.ui-btn").text(text);
    });
}).change();
```

> Updated **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/ye727qps/2/)**